# recovering windows 10 password using windows 8

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

In my laptop both windows 8 and 10 are installed side by side. Unfortunately I forgot the password of windows 10 but still can use windows 8. Is there any way to obtain windows 10 password using my other windows, i.e. windows 8.

Comment: No; You will have to enable the built-in Administrator account using WinRE.  See my answer on that subject on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover any windows password, you can only change it or clear it. The typical way that i do it is to boot into a linux live USB/CD (Ubuntu/Mint/Debian) and use `chntpw` to activate the Administrator account and clear the password.

Once i'm in the live environment i use a file explorer to mount my windows hard drive. Then i open a terminal and do the following in order:

1. `cd /media/livecd/mountedvolume/Windows/System32/config`
2. `sudo apt-get install chntpw`
3. `sudo chntpw SAM -u Administrator` or whichever user you want to clear the password for.
4. Here you can tap 2 and 1 to clear and activate the Administrator password or whichever user you decided to modify.
5. Press `Q` and accept to write the changes and you're done!

There are other tools that you can use that produce the same effect such as [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and [Active@](http://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. chntpw deletes the password in the SAM file. I am thinking a similar thing. From windows 8 I can reach the SAM file of windows 10. But I could not find utility that runs on windows which decrypts the SAM file. Is it possible to decrypt SAM file or is there a similar utility like chntpw that runs on windows?

Comment: if you could decrypt a password then there would be no point in having a password in the first place. Passwords are usually hashed but not sure about SAM, im sure its hashed as well. Once a password is hashed, you cant "decrypt" it as hashing is one way encryption. You can only compare a password to the hash and see if it matches. Else you can only clear it. Another option that comes to mind would be Cain and Able, not sure if its against the rules to mention that and i dont think that is very safe to run on your PC regardless.