# Unlock Windows 10 with a DOS boot disk?

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery

I forgot my Win10 password. I have a disk which was a xp install disk, with a DOS environment and some disk tools(Ghost, etc). However, there's no PE. Can I unlock my computer without formatting the install disk or use another disk?

I tried to modify the `sethc.exe` and `magnify.exe` in DOS with `NTFS4DOS`, but the modification sliently fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rights of admin after I disabled all admin accounts in my computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer)

Comment: @Ramhound I think it's more directly a similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1387358/ , but I have existed tool that may be helpful(like https://superuser.com/questions/1252620/ , but different tool)

Comment: The duplicate question’s answer is the proper solution to your problem

Comment: @Ramhound No it doesn't

Comment: You want Administrator access to your system.  Enabling the built-in Administrator will allow you to reset your existing account password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if I forgot my Windows password?](https://superuser.com/questions/72244/what-can-i-do-if-i-forgot-my-windows-password)

Comment: See my answer here....https://superuser.com/a/247953/40928